# Entity Framework - stange behaviour

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 3 simplest tables:

http://magicscreenshot.blob.core.windows.net/screenshots/udYWngOVQEM.jpg

and relationships among them:

http://magicscreenshot.blob.core.windows.net/screenshots/zTK28gBgkEc.jpg

If I create a new project from zero  and create Entity Model (from DB) I receive correct EF model:

http://magicscreenshot.blob.core.windows.net/screenshots/ZZg8gpzXFkE.jpg

But when I try to do the same for my real project - created EF model is very strange

http://magicscreenshot.blob.core.windows.net/screenshots/WfKgc8vBDU8.jpg

as we can see, it created a new entity "SectionSite" with relationship to Site and no relationship to Section. Why it happened and how to fix it?

Comment: How did you add in your new relationship? Was it manually added or via "Update Model from Database"? Replicating your table design in EF 6.0, I don't seem to have the same issue, it quite happily adds in the navigation property.

Comment: "Update Model from Database". As you can see, I tried to do it for both projects - my real project and empty test project. The empty test project creates DB model correctly, real project - no for the same actions :(

Comment: When updating the model is "Include foreign key columns in the model" checked, are both projects targeting the same connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate this if you added in your Section and SectionSite table independently of adding your Site table. This creates the link the following link.

[image: Broken EDMX Model]

To resolve this missmatch of identity you can either.

1. Remove and re-add Site, Section, and SectionSite all at the same time.

OR

1. Right click "Add a new association" between Site and SectionSite and un-check "Add foreign key properties to the 'Section' entity."

[image: Add Association]

2. Then you need to select the created relationship, properties -> Referential Constraint and update to meet your FK relationship.

[image: Modify Referential Constraint]

3. Once your happy, right click and validate your model and it should now work?

Answer (score 0):

With Entity Framework you don't have to create a mapping table.

If you let your Section refer to multiple Sites (ICollection) and let your Site refer to multiple Sections (ICollection), Entity Framework will create a SectionSite or SiteSection table for you.

Comment: I don't use "Code First" approach, but "Update Model from Database"